# Android:obter valor de RadioButton

Tags: android

Olá, estou com um problema que não consigo resolver.
Tenho um `dialog` onde tenho um `RadioGroup` com 2 `Radio Buttons` e um botão `OK`.

Pretendo obter o valor do radio Button selecionado quando clico no OK, mas estou a obter a Excepção "`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference`".

O código é o seguinte:

```
public void test(){


    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_currency);
    dialog.setTitle("Test");
    dialog.show();

    //selected=new RadioButton(this.getApplicationContext());
    radioG = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            Log.d("Base ACtivity","selectedId:"+selectedId);

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            selected = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            String a = selected.getText().toString();

            String optionSelected = ((RadioButton) v).getText().toString();
        }
    });
}
```

O problema está na linha `String a = selected.getText().toString());` . Tenho por defeito um radioButton seleccionado no ficheiro XML através de `android:checked="true"`, o que faz com que `selectedId` nunca seja null.

Será que poderiam ajudar?

Comment: O erro não será na linha `String optionSelected = ((RadioButton) v).getText().toString();`? Note que `v` é um *button* e você está a fazer o *cast* para *RadioButton*

Comment: @ramaral, sim o erro é aí, o v é um button?

Comment: É porque o *OnClickListener*, neste caso, foi associado ao um botão: `ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()....`

Comment: @ramaral nao tou a perceber..foi associado ao botão ok, porque eu quero que quando se clique no botão ok, se obtenha o valor do radioButton

Comment: Sim isso está correcto, no entanto o `v` é um botão. Vou colocar uma resposta.

Comment: Não há necessidade de colocar resposta, comente ou apague a linha `String optionSelected = ((RadioButton) v).getText().toString();`  o texto do *RadioButton* selecionado está na *string* `a`

Comment: @ramaral o problema esta mesmo na linha String a = selected.getText().toString();

Comment: Quando disse que ia postar uma resposta foi por ter pensado que o seu código poderia ter algum problema. Fiz alguns testes e não encontrei nada de errado. No entanto parti do príncipio que `radioG` é um *RadioGroup* e que tem um *RadioButton* selecionado. O que é escrito no log pela linha `Log.d("Base ACtivity","selectedId:"+selectedId);`?

Comment: @ramaral, selectedId:2131296322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é você estar a usar o método `findViewById()` da *Activity* e não do *RadioGroup*.
O método procura uma *View* com esse *id* na *Activity* como ela não o tem ele retorna `null`.

Altere a linha:

```
selected = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
```

para

```
selected = (RadioButton) radioG.findViewById(selectedId);
```

Comment: Obrigada!Funcionou!

Comment: Quase que me escapava. O que me desviou a atenção foi a linha `String optionSelected = ((RadioButton) v).getText().toString();` que daria erro também.